# "[object ErrorEvent]" thrown in angular app testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to test that my function is well called after button clicked. what is the best way to do it?

I have this error with the flowing test

**Error:**

```
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

**My test spec:**

```
describe('myComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'myFunction');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Should test that myFunction is called when button clicked', () => {
     let params = "VALUE";

     let myBtn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.item:nth-child(2) .delete'));
     myBtn.triggerEventHandler('click', null);


     expect(component.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params);
  });
});
```

Comment: What version of jasmine-core are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
myBtn.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
```

for:

```
myBtn.nativeElement.click();
```

Comment: thx @lain, i used ```myBtn = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.myBtn'); myBtn.click();```, but this solution ```spyOn(component, 'myFunction').and.stub();``` that solved my problem